# How do I use CoffeeScript in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, templates, coffeescript, controller-action

In my controller's `create` action, I have the following:

```
def create
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.save
      format.js { render 'success.js' }
    else
      format.js { render 'failed.js' }
    end
  end
end
```

In my `app/views/comments/failed.js.coffee`, I have:

```
alert 'Write smth!' if $("#comments_error").length == 0
```

I receive the following error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template comments/failed,
  inherited_resources/base/failed, application/failed with
  {:locale=>[:en, :en],
   :formats=>[:js, :html],
   :handlers=>[:haml, :builder, :erb]})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the time of this writing Rails does not support responding with a coffee-script file.
This however is going to change.

Meanwhile in your Gemfile add:

```
gem 'coffeebeans'
```

then name your views action.js.coffee

As added bonus the file will pass through erb first, even if it's not declared in the file name.

Comment: I have one more question, if I have some ruby code in my action.js.coffee file, what I should do? I tried rename action.js.coffee to action.js.coffee.erb, but I received error: ActionView::MissingTemplate